# Change Vite proxy location automatically in dev vs prod builds?

Tags: typescript, devops, http-proxy, vite

In my single page application I'm developing I'm using Vite and in my `vite.config.ts` file I have the following proxy:

```
proxy: {
  '/v1': {
    target: 'https://127.0.0.1:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false
  }
}
```

Is there a way to change this target depending on whether it is in the production environment? Something like:

```
proxy: {
  '/v1': {
    target: isDev ? 'https://127.0.0.1:8080' : 'https://api.example.com',
    changeOrigin: isDev,
    secure: !isDev
  }
}
```

That is, in my local environment I want to develop against my local server, such that my fetch API calls like `fetch("/v1/get-posts")` get forwarded to `https://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/get-posts`, but in my production build (which I create via `vite build`), they will instead be forwarded to: `https://api.example.com/v1/get-posts`

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dev server and its proxy config aren't bundled into the build output, so your goal does not make much sense practically. However, you technically can run the dev server in production mode via the `mode` flag, so perhaps that's what you meant.

In that case, you can use a [conditional config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#conditional-config), where `isDev` would be `mode === 'development'`:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

const defaultConfig = {
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
}

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  if (command === 'serve') {
            
    const isDev = mode === 'development'

    return {
      ...defaultConfig,
      server: {
        proxy: {
          '/v1': {
            target: isDev ? 'https://127.0.0.1:8080' : 'https://api.example.com',
            changeOrigin: isDev,
            secure: !isDev
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    return defaultConfig
  }
})
```

Comment: @JamesP Indeed, hosting the Vite server might not be recommended in some production environments. Setting up a proxy can be done in many ways, but the solution you pick will likely depend on how your app is hosted. If you don't have control of the host or proxy settings (e.g., hosting on GitHub), you can't setup your own proxy on that host. Otherwise, if you're on a custom server, you could setup just about any proxy server (e.g., nginx, express, koa, etc.) adjacent to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike **create-react-app**, **Vite** does not provide the proxying configurations after the build, but only for development.

So, in order to support the build, you have to manually check for the environment variable to see if you're in production or development as follows:

for example, this is the baseUrl property in redux-toolkit-query, or fetch(), or even axios(), whatever you're using

```js
// for example, this is the baseUrl property in redux-toolkit-query, or fetch(), or even axios(), whatever you're using
import.meta.env.MODE === 'development' ? `api/v1` : HOST + '/v1'
```

Assuming this is your vite.config.js file (as an example, it doesn't have to be exactly like mine):

```js
process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) }
return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: process.env.VITE_mainAPI_host,
          changeOrigin: true,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
```