# How to change the URL prefix for fetch calls depending on dev vs prod environment?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-proxy, vite

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534594/change-vite-proxy-location-automatically-in-dev-vs-prod-builds).

I'm using Vite, and the dev server comes with a proxy server, such that I can specify a proxy like this:

```
proxy: {
  '/v1': {
    target: 'https://127.0.0.1:8080',
    changeOrigin: true
  }
}
```

And then a [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) call called like this:

```
fetch("/v1/get-users");
```

Will effectively be transformed into this:

```
fetch("https://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/get-users");
```

This works perfectly, because that is where my API server is hosted on my dev environment.

However, this will fail on prod, because *there* my API server is instead hosted at `https://api.mysite.com`

Ideally I could just somehow express that my `prod` prefix should instead be `https://api.mysite.com` instead of `https://127.0.0.1:8080`, but apparently Vite does not use a proxy server with its build output.

How do people normally handle this? The only thing I could think of is perhaps something like this, but it seems a bit gross:

```
function getPrefix() {
  return location.hostname === "mysite.com" ? "https://api.mysite.com" : "";
}

fetch(getPrefix() + "/v1/get-users");
```

But it just seems kind of messy, and cumbersome to have to add that to every fetch call.

I could make a fetch wrapper as well, but I'm just wondering if this sort of thing *is* how people solve this to begin with, or if there is a more "best-practice" solution for this common problem.

Comment: `fetch("/v1/get-users");` doesn't get replaced to `fetch("https://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/get-users");`. Vite creates a proxy for you, i.e. a server that forwards your request to the actual server. Doesn't seem like you should have an issue with it...

Comment: Right, but regardless this proxy will not exist in the prod environment, because Vite does not compile a proxy into the build output. So regardless the `fetch("v1/get-users")` call wouldn't work, no? Because it would be sent to `https://example.com/v1/get-users` instead of `https://api.example.com/v1/get-users`, right?

Comment: Ah, okay. Vite uses Rollup, so you could use the [`rollup-replace-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-replace) to replace the value with whatever. Like in your string you can do `fetch("__SITE_BASE__/v1/get_users")`, and in development configure the replacement from `"__SITE_BASE__"` to `""`, but in production do `"https://api.mysite.com"`.

Comment: Hmm, okay, is that the ideal solution for this? That seems _okay_, although it's a bit ugly I guess (having to prefix all the fetch calls with that). So do I have to `npm install` that plugin, or is it already enabled? How do I use it with Vite? Also, is that preferred over the solution I posted in my original question (using the `getPrefix` function)

Comment: Yes, you need to install that plugin. I'm posting an answer with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (and cleanest) solution I can think of is to replace the values in your code. This is often done for things like `process.env.NODE_ENV` or the like, but this is certainly a standard usecase.

You can use <s>[`rollup-replace-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-replace)</s> [`vite-plugin-replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-replace), which allows you to replace values in your code.

Change `vite.config.js` to:

```js
// ...
import { replaceCodePlugin } from "vite-plugin-replace";

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    replaceCodePlugin({
      replacements: [
        {
          from: "__SITE_BASE__",
          to: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
                ? "https://api.mysite.com" // production site
                : "" // development proxy,
        }
      ],
    }),
  ],
});
```

In your code, you would do:

```js
fetch("__SITE_BASE__/v1/get-users");
```

This would be advantageous over your current approach, as firstly, you can easily change your site base (instead of digging in your code to find that function), secondly, it's easier to write, and lastly you have static data, so you don't have to call the function every time the user loads the page, which is better for performance anyways.